# Sending mail with phpMailer but works on localhost

Tags: php, localhost, phpmailer, web-hosting

I am having an issue with phpMailer. It works fine on the localhost but gives an authentication error when I upload it to the web host.

"CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data"

The settings are smtp.gmail.com, Port 587 with TLS encryption as stated on http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm

I replaced the real website address with www.mywebsiteaddress.com.

Here:

```
2014-08-28 22:55:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-lp.linkdatacenter.net ESMTP Exim 4.82 #2 Thu, 28 Aug 2014 22:55:00 +0000 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2014-08-28 22:55:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mywebsiteaddress.com
2014-08-28 22:55:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-lp.linkdatacenter.net Hello sigmaengco.com [213.131.64.210] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP
2014-08-28 22:55:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2014-08-28 22:55:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
2014-08-28 22:55:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mywebsiteaddress.com
2014-08-28 22:55:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-lp.linkdatacenter.net Hello sigmaengco.com [213.131.64.210] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP 2014-08-28 22:55:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2014-08-28 22:55:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2014-08-28 22:55:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: bGl0dGxlcGVhcmxzY2VudGVyQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
2014-08-28 22:55:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2014-08-28 22:55:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: dXRvcGlhdXRvcGlh
2014-08-28 22:55:02 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data
2014-08-28 22:55:02 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data
2014-08-28 22:55:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2014-08-28 22:55:02 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 lp.linkdatacenter.net closing connection
SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Here is the relevant part of the code, I replaced the real information with fake info.

```
    require_once('PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'mypassword';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                  // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL 
    $mail->From = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'my website name';
    //$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('myotheremail@yahoo.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
```

Comment: This should give you a good idea of why it failed: `SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data 2014-08-28 22:55:02`

Comment: @l'L'l It is the same exact password used on the localhost which works fine. It has to do with the settings on the web-hosting server.

Comment: For the testing: Your password should contain no special characters and no umlauts.

Comment: @FranzHolzinger the password is made only from alphabets.

Comment: You must setup your Google account for the 2 step authentification.
[2 step autheintivication](https://support.google.com/a/answer/184711?hl=en)

Comment: @FranzHolzinger still works on local & gives the same error at the web-host.

Comment: Why would it be any kind of surprise that local and remote servers use different authentication?

Comment: [Here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31297/gmail-rejects-smtp-password-with-2-factor-authentication) should be the solution.

Comment: @Synchro so if either ssl or tls is required for google smtp server. How can I overcome this at the remote server?

Comment: You're trying to use your google auth credentials on some other server that's nothing to do with google! Nothing to do with TLS. It could be that your ISP is redirecting to their own mail server, so you should ask them to stop doing that.

Comment: @Synchro I asked them before about that but they said they allow connection to any smtp server. They did say "our encryption is: no encryption" but google smtp requires TLS/SSL.

Comment: If you're requesting `smtp.gmail.com`, but ending up connecting to `lp.linkdatacenter.net` (i.e. not google), either your DNS is being spoofed, or their firewall is redirecting you somewhere else. Either way it's not good.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and the message sent successfully.

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "mail.mysite.com"; //email account on my hosting
$mail->Port = 25; // port on non ssl-setting
$mail->Username = "myusername";  //username to log into hosting
$mail->Password = "mypassword";  //password to log into hosting
```